# Push to new remote with LFS

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, git-lfs

A remote repository (**origin** @ BitBucket) got deleted. I have a local version of that project and I'm trying to recreate this repository from my local copy.

The deleted project used LFS. I have created a new empty repository on GitLab and added it as a secondary remote named "**origin2**".

When I try to do `git push origin2 master` my upload process gets stuck at `Uploading LFS objects:  50% (2553/5107), 783 MB | 0 B/s`

I tried to do `git push origin2 master --no-verify` and this worked. But if I now clone this new repository from GitLab and try to open the project I get all kinds of errors which I assume is because some files previously "handled" by LFS are missing.

Is there a way I can fully recreate the repository from my local copy?

This is how my config looks:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:company/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[lfs "https://bitbucket.org/company/project.git/info/lfs"]
    locksverify = false
[remote "origin2"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:company/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin2/*
[lfs "https://gitlab.com/company/project.git/info/lfs"]
    locksverify = true
```

Comment: Have you tried `git lfs push origin2 --all` ? Also have you configured HTTPS credentials for `origin2` ? If you haven't configured HTTPS credentials, that may be why the push is getting stuck. (LFS must go through https)

Comment: Yes, I have tried `git lfs push origin2 --all` it still gets stuck at around 50%. `git lfs env` gives me 2 endpoints both starting with https, one for each remote (old and new) so I assume this means that the new repository also has the lfs configured.

Comment: I also added how my config file looks currently to the original post.

Comment: Hmm. Only thing I would think to do at this point would be to enable git debug/curl_trace logging and see if there's any obvious reason it's stopping there. I might also suspect server configuration, but that's highly unlikely since this is `gitlab.com` not self-hosted. I think you should also get explicit errors if you've hit your repository storage limits, but may be worth checking.

Comment: The local repository may not hold all the lfs objects. Some of them are just gone as the remote repository has been removed. Is it possible to ask BitBucket for recovery? If yes, then you could make a full clone with all data and push them to gitlab's new repository. Or maybe there is a full clone somewhere else?

Comment: @sytech enabling debug/curl trace logging doesn't log anything, still gets stuck at "Uploading LFS objects" stage, with no further logs.

Comment: @ElpieKay unfortunately there is no way to recover the repo. Maybe you are right, and some LFS objects are just gone with the repo.

Comment: `--no-verify` skips the pre-push hook. I haven't looked closely enough at Git-LFS, but I suspect the pre-push hook is where it sends the large files to the large-file server. If that's getting stuck at 50%, that's because 50% is the point at which the large files are getting stuck. You could either wait longer (to see if it makes progress past 50% after some hours or days), or investigate why it gets stuck.

Comment: It is not always 50%, it has stopped anywhere between 40% and 70%. And I have now waited over 8 hours and still no progress. How can I investigate this? since curl_trace logging doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have all of the LFS objects on the original server, then you have lost data.  Unlike the Git data, the entirety of the LFS data is not stored in your local repository and is typically only stored on the server.

The `pre-push` hook, which is skipped with `--no-verify`, is where LFS files are typically pushed, which is why pushing this way seems to work.

The proper way to push LFS objects to a new location is to fetch them with `git lfs fetch --all` and then push with `git lfs push --all NEW-REMOTE`.  However, if you have no way to fetch the old data, then it's just gone.